# error compiling ompl_ros_interface tutorial (calling joint space planner)

Tags: ros, ompl-ros-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
I am experiencing problem when compiling the calling joint spcae planner.
System running on ubuntu 12.04 with ros fuerte.
Error message:

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['ompl_tutorial_example']                   
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/anshar/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130411-121509
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['ompl_tutorial_example'] to:
['ompl_tutorial_example']
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs              
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-6] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-6] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                  
[rosmake-6] Starting >>> ompl_tutorial_example [ make ]                         
[ rosmake ] All 37 linesmpl_tutorial_example: 2.2 s... [ 1 Active 4/5 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package ompl_tutorial_example
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/roslisp.cmake
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  CMake Warning:
    Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:
  
      CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
  
  
  -- Build files have been written to: /home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/ompl_tutorial_example/build
  cd build && make -j8 -l8
  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/ompl_tutorial_example/build'
  make[2]: Entering directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/ompl_tutorial_example/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/ompl_tutorial_example/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/ompl_tutorial_example/build'
  [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/ompl_tutorial_example/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/ompl_tutorial_example/build'
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/ompl_tutorial_example/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/ompl_tutorial_example/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/ompl_tutorial_example/build'
  [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ompl_joint_goal.dir/src/ompl_joint_goal.o
  /home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/ompl_tutorial_example/src/ompl_joint_goal.cpp:3:48: fatal error: motion_planning_msgs/GetMotionPlan.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/ompl_joint_goal.dir/src/ompl_joint_goal.o] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/ompl_tutorial_example/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ompl_joint_goal.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/ompl_tutorial_example/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/ompl_tutorial_example/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package ompl_tutorial_example written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/anshar/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130411-121509/ompl_tutorial_example/build_output.log
[rosmake-6] Finished <<< ompl_tutorial_example [FAIL] [ 2.27 seconds ]          
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package ompl_tutorial_example. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 5 packages with 1 failures.                                   
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/anshar/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130411-121509
```

I am referring to: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ompl_ros_interface/Tutorials/Calling%20the%20joint%20space%20planner

is the missing file part of the package in motion_planning_msgs?
Looking forward to any assistance.
Thanks

Ryan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60436/error-compiling-ompl_ros_interface-tutorial-(calling-joint-space-planner)/) by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2013-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*It error states it could not find that file. Is the motion_planning_msgs package in your [ROS_PACKAGE_PATH](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_PACKAGE_PATH)?*

```
rospack find motion_planning_msgs
```

---

As you can see in the output the compiler finds a reference to the old package at line 3 in the mentioned file:

```
  /home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/ompl_tutorial_example/src/ompl_joint_goal.cpp:3:48: fatal error: motion_planning_msgs/GetMotionPlan.h: No such file or directory
```

So if your file actually looks different, your make is broken. For a dull test call `make clean` before.

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2013-04-16**:
it is not in my ros package, but some sources mentioned that motion_planning_msgs has changed to arm_navigation_msgs. GetMotionPlan.h does exist in arm_navigation_msgs. Yet, after changing, the compilation still produces the same error.

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2013-04-16**:
I Just figure out that arm_navigations_msgs appear twice in my ros path:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/arm_navigation/arm_navigation_msgs/srv_gen/cpp/include/arm_navigation_msgs$, however it doesn't recognise the directory -> fatal error: arm_navigation_msgs/GetMotionPlan.h: No such file or directory

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-04-17**:
Have you replaced every occurrence of motion_planning_msgs ([manifest](http://ros.org/wiki/Manifest), that other include, CMakeLists if at all...) Why do you mean twice? The package-named directory inside msg_gen or srv_gen is correct, but of course shouldn't be in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH itself.

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2013-04-17**:
Thanks for responding. I am following this tutorial: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ompl_ros_interface/Tutorials/Calling%20the%20joint%20space%20planner , I have replaced all the occurrence of motion_planning_msgs in my example_ompl_tutorials directory.any assistance would be appreciated

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2013-05-09**:
I just reinstalled ros and re-do everything and managed to successfully compile it according to the tutorial. I decided to reinstall after trying sudo apt-get update my system and it reported some missing dependencies.Thank you for your respond.

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-05-13**:
Glad you got it. Maybe `apt-get install -f` or `apt-get dist-upgrade` could have helped. Haven't thought about that.

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2013-05-20**:
I tried before reinstalling but didn't work.Thanks a lot felix for your follow up respond. :)